# wcftestclient.exe 'has stopped working' 

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, wcf-client

When using the WCF Test Client tool, if I invoke a method via eager loading like below:

```
.Include("entity name")
```

the client tool crashes with a "stackoverflow" exception.

If I make a call **without** the Include statement, it works fine.

Note that either way, if I execute them via another type of client, I can see in the WCF trace message log, that the data gets xferred just fine for both. It's just that the **WCF client tool can't seem to handle** calls via EnityFramework and eager loading when data from more than one entity is brought back.

I guess there is not a way around this error with this tool. Looks like I have to resort to testing with my other client making the call instead of simply invoking the method via the WCF test client tool.

Anyone see this same scenario. If so and if there is a work around, I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: Could you please post your entities? I guess this is something to do with a property that points to itself and results in a stackoverflow exception

Comment: When viewing the ORM designer, there is a one to many relationship  from the Customer entity to the Projects entity. Not sure what you mean by posting my entities here. If you want me to post some specific code, I can....